# How to replace money "xxx" By Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Example**

```
฿33.00 => ฿3X.XX
฿111.00 => ฿1XX.XX
฿33,333.00 => ฿3X,XXX.XX
```

How to replace money "xxx" By Javascript Or jQuery

Comment: You can use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to achieve this.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and **expected output**.

Comment: You definitely don't need jQuery for that. JS `.replace()` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like that :

```js
    var input="฿33.00";
    if (input.length > 2 && input[0] == "฿" && !isNaN(input[1])) {
        var output = input.substring(0,2);
        for (var i=2; i<input.length; i++) {
            output += isNaN(input[i]) ? input[i] : "X";
        }
        console.log(output);
    }
```

In this code we first check that the transformation is applicable (input has at least 3 characters, first char is the currency symbol, second is a digit), then we create a string that starts with the first two characters of the input and which we continue by iterating over the input, adding an "X" to the output if it's a digit and the character (a dot or comma assumedly) otherwise.

Comment: That loop is very inelegant in my opinion

Comment: @mplungjan I haven't coded anything in JS in years, what would you propose? I mainly wanted to give an alternative to the regex solutions as I believe regex isn't a very appropriate tool for that problem

Comment: If you see my answer you might see that regex is very appropriate in this case. I use it twice with very clear results

Comment: Yeah, your solution is fine, I was afraid of a pure regex solution using lookbehinds to solve the problem in one `.replace()` without any splitting, but that wouldn't even be possible in JS. Anyway do you think there's any way I can make my loop more elegant, or is it just that you think that it's not a good idea to iterate over the characters of the string explicitely and that regex is the only elegant solution?

Comment: It is the looping and concatenation I dislike. You are using a side-effect of comma and fullstop are isNaN instead of just replacing all digits in one regex

Comment: I disagree about my use of isNaN being considered a side-effect, I find very appropriate to test whether a character is a digit using isNan. And while the regex will certainly be more efficient, it still has to do the same kind of things behind the scenes : it must iterate over each character, test if they belong to the character class, and handle a new string in which it concatenates the replaced characters

Comment: True, but that will be code that has been tested by millions

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex,  map and replace

```js
const lines = `฿33.00
฿111.00
฿33,333.00`.split(/\s+/)

const res = lines.map(line => {
  let [a, b, c] = line.match(/(฿\d)(.*)/); // capture the ฿+first digit plus rest
  return b + c.replace(/[0-9]/g, "X"); // replace the numbers in the rest
});
console.log(res)
```